# Build Visual Studio 6 project without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nmake

I have inherited a Visual Studio 6 C++ project. The project builds fine in Visual Studio 6 but I failed to compile certain files in the project with a gcc compiler. These issues relate to forward declarations and probably other issues. For the mean-time, I'm not interested in fixing these problems since the code is horrible. The code is also windows dependant since it uses win32 to communicate with com ports.

So, I wish to compile with an ms compiler (and build and link...) but I don't have access anymore to Visual Studio due to company policy...

What options are open to me?

THanks for your help,

Barry.

Comment: You can't use something like the Visual Studio Express edition? Or are you prohibited from using VS at all?

Comment: "I don't have access anymore to Visual Studio" You mean to VS6 or to all VS? (Which versions do you still have?) Do you have access to the compilers in the platform SDK at least?

Comment: It's very possible that the code base you inherited relies on features of the VC++ 6 compiler that are not well-supported by other compilers. If using VC++ 6 is not an option, you're probably going to have to modify the code. And even once you get it to compile, I recommend testing to make sure that everything still works as expected.

Comment: Did you check for the Makefile that VS creates for all projects ?

Comment: My company has no VS licences anymore since development has been moved to linux. However, I'm working with an old test framework that still requires a windows app. I will port it at a later stage. I asked if they could install vs on my machine and they said no...

Comment: @Baz Have you told them that VS Express is free and will save you a lot of time that you could invest in a project that has higher priority? This is how i mostly get software that is off-limits to others but that in edge case is just needed to save time/money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try downloading the free (as in beer) windows SDK.  It's been a while, but I believe that these low level tools, such cl, link and make are available though these.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924

But you probably will need to massage the code a little, so you might need to deal with the win api a little bit too.

Just to clarify, this is free and not associated with VS, so unless your company has some rather restrictive policies, you should be able to download and use the Windows SDK fine.  Furthermore, the compiler tools should be somewhat friendly to VS6.

Comment: Yeah VS Express could build the project for me. I had to import the project files by hand and change from unicode to the multibyte charset.